# Run single JUnit test with new code

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unrooted Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120889/unrooted-tests)

I've a meven project and I integrated Junit for testing some methods. When I lunch Run-> Maven Install all tests are executed but if I write a new test and then I try to lunch it JUnit returned my an InitializationError of UnrootedTest? Why?

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends `TestCase` somewhere in its hierarchy, you have to use the `JUnit 3` test runner listed in the drop down under run configurations. Using the `JUnit 4` runner (the default I believe) causes that unrooted test phenomenon to occur.

Check this question, might help: [Unrooted Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120889/1268844)