# Unrooted Tests for TestSuites

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4, junit3

I want to create a test suite builder for some common use cases in our company (like Google Guave does for collections).

So I create my builder, and some classes extending either `TestSuite` or `TestCase` that get added if needed. However running everything in Eclipse (Mars 4.5.1 - don't judge) shows the tests as "Unrooted Tests" and the view is not able to mark them as either successful nor failed:

[image: JUnit View]

Maven brings the following exception (but it's Maven, I can burn that bridge when I get to it, I'm not convinced it has anything to do with the above):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project org.acme.project Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120889/unrooted-tests) state this is due to using JUnit 4 for the JUnit 3 class `TestCase` (which is not deprecated, so...), in which case the question would be: How do I convert this code to JUnit 4?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ MyTest.Suite.class })
public class MyTest {

    public static class Suite {

        public static TestSuite suite() {
            final TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("My Test Suite");
            suite.addTest(new CompoundTester(value -> new MyTester(value), "A", "B"));
            return suite;
        }
    }

    public static class CompoundTester extends TestSuite {

        public CompoundTester(final Function<String, TestCase> testFactory, final String... values) {
            String name = "unknown";
            for (final String value : values) {
                final TestCase testCase = testFactory.apply(value);
                name = testCase.getName();
                addTest(new TestCase(value.toString()) {

                    @Override
                    public void run(final TestResult result) {
                        testCase.run(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            setName(name);
        }
    }

    public static class MyTester extends TestCase {

        private final String object;

        public MyTester(final String object) {
            super("testSomething");
            this.object = object;
        }

        public void testSomething() {
            Assert.assertNotNull(this.object);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if the `run` method of the anonymous `TestCase` class looks like this:

```
@Override
public final void run(final TestResult result) {
    result.startTest(this);
    result.runProtected(this, () -> testCase.run());
    result.endTest(this);
}
```

No idea why, though.